# Downcast from Any to Specific type

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore DB "sales", which has one column called `saleapproveddate`. There are 2 levels of people, one who logs sale and other approves the sale logs. While logging sale, I save the `saleapproveddate` as `NSNull()` (which saves as `nil` in firestore DB field). Approver can update the `saleapproveddate` as `TimeStamp`, but if the approver never approves the sale log, it remains as `nil` in firestore DB field. So it can have either `nil` or `TimeStamp` type.

I have model Sales

```
class Sale  {

    var saleapprovedate : Any?
}
```

When I load the data from firestore, I tried to downcast the `saleapprovedate` as Any

```
let approvedDate = document[SaleProperties.paidDate.rawValue] as Any
```

But the real challenge is, `saleapprovedate` can have either `nil` or `Timestamp`. How do I check for type condition, convert to specific type and display in label?

Below is what I tried:

```
While loading data:
sale.saleapprovedate = document[SaleProperties.saleapprovedate.rawValue] as Any

while displaying data:
let saleItem = sales[indexPath.row]
let paidDate = saleItem.saleapprovedate
if paidDate == nil {
            cell.paidDateLabelContainer.text = "Yet to pay"
            cell.paidStatusImageView.isHidden = true
        }

        else  {
            let paidDateTimeStamp = saleItem.saleapprovedate as! Timestamp
           let convertedPaidDate = self.convertTimestampToDate(timeStamp: paidDateTimeStamp)
            cell.paidDateLabelContainer.text = convertDateToString(date: convertedPaidDate)
            cell.paidStatusImageView.isHidden = false

        }
```

But the above code is not updating the cell label properly. I have two data, one has `saleapprovedate` as `Timestamp` and other as `nil`. Both the cell label is displaying as "Yet to pay". What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you storing nil? It my not be necessary as if the key doesn't exist, then it's assumed to be nil. So you can *let approvedDate = document[xxxxx] ?? "Yet To Pay* so approvedDate would either be the approvedDate (string) or 'Yet To Pay"

Comment: Thank you! With your suggestion and little googling, I resolved the issue. BTW, sometimes, Any, Anyobject, optional will make us mad :)

Comment: If `saleapprovedate` *can have either `nil` or `Timestamp`* why do you declare the variable as unspecified as possible rather than specific `Timestamp?`. Don't fight Swift's strong type system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Modal :
var incentivepaiddate : Any?

Array :
var sales : [Sale] = [Sale]()

Loading data from firestore :

for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
let sale = Sale()
sale.incentivepaiddate = document[SaleProperties.incentivepaiddate.rawValue]
self.sales.append(sale)
}
```

Checking for nil, downcasting to a specific type and display data in cell

```
let saleItem = sales[indexPath.row]
let paidDate = saleItem.incentivepaiddate

 if let paid = paidDate {

            let paidDateTimeStamp = paid as? Timestamp
            let convertedPaidDate = self.convertTimestampToDate(timeStamp: paidDateTimeStamp!)
            cell.paidDateLabelContainer.text = convertDateToString(date: convertedPaidDate)
        }
        else {
            cell.paidDateLabelContainer.text = "Yet to pay"
            cell.paidStatusImageView.isHidden = true
        }
```

Hope this helps someone!